# What is the difference between "unknown" and "undefined" trust?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, web-of-trust

When you `trust` a GnuPG key, you can choose one of these five options (and I'm assuming the same options exist in other OpenPGP tools):

> 1 = I don't know or won't say (**undefined**)
>    2 = I do NOT trust (**never**)
>    3 = I trust **marginally**
>    4 = I trust **fully**
>    5 = I trust **ultimately**

However, there is a "sixth" option that doesn't show up in the list: if you haven't yet set trust for a key, it shows up as **unknown**.

Is there a reason GnuPG makes a distinction between the two? Is **undefined** trust treated differently than **unknown**, or is the distinction just for personal reference?

Comment: Unknown means you've never seen the cert before.  Undefined means you've seen it, recognized it, and gave it the lowest trust level.

Comment: @raz I thought **never** was the lowest trust level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options 2 to 5 (never, marginally, fully and ultimately trusted) correspond to a definite decision made by you on the trust level which influences validity calculation.

*Unknown* says, you haven't made any decision at all and thus is special, indicating no value at all (you might consider it some kind of `NULL` value). 
Option 1, *undefined* is similar and has similar outcome regarding validity caluclation, but is a statement you can issue on *not* wanting to decide on the key's trust level. You might want to use it as future reference instead of not setting any trust value.